# Change a column of all duplicated row to same value

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Here I have a df with multiple ID belonging to the same email. I want to change all duplicated Email's ID to the same for each unique Email and not dropping any rows.

Sample DF:

```
 ID      Email
 1    a@gmail.com
 2    a@gmail.com
 3    b@gmail.com
 4    c@gmail.com
 5    c@gmail.com
```

Desire DF:

```
 ID      Email
 1    a@gmail.com
 1    a@gmail.com
 3    b@gmail.com
 4    c@gmail.com
 4    c@gmail.com
```

Comment: dataframe['id'] = dataframe.groupby('email').id.transform('first')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC

```
df['ID']=df.groupby('Email').ID.transform('first')
df
Out[195]: 
   ID        Email
0   1  a@gmail.com
1   1  a@gmail.com
2   3  b@gmail.com
3   4  c@gmail.com
4   4  c@gmail.com
```